# Rails Admin - limit group output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have model DocumentCategory which has many Documents, and its model looks like this:

```
class DocumentCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :documents
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      group :documents do
        label 'Docs'
          field :documents do
          ...
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is - I have thousands of documents in each category, so I need to limit list to last N uploaded elements or (which is better) add pagination to this list (it presented by row of tabs by default in Rails admin). Is there any options in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can paginate the has_and_belongs_to_many control, you can search on it, and you could scope its results like this:

```
class DocumentCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :documents
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      group :documents do
        label 'Docs'
          field :documents do
            associated_collection_scope do
              proc { |scope|
                scope.where('updated_at < ?', 30.days.ago)
              }
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that would also scope the results so you'll have to check within that proc if a query was issued and do not scope in that cases

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not limit output at all. But it doesn't break the page at least) Thank you for your trying to help, anyway.